# Does React unmount actually remove elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've created a component that renders only an empty canvas element.  After initialising in use effect, I draw a little square then start an interval to redraw the square at different locations.  Initially I did this without using state and just stored the value in a local variable, the square redrew as expected and the component wasn't repeatedly unmounted and rendered.

I then tried putting the variable into state to see if the canvas would be cleared/deleted on unmount and recreated fresh and clean on render, but it isn't.  The component is constantly getting unmounted and re-rendered but it always seems to render the contents of the old canvas.

Is this virtual DOM at work?  I can't seem to find anything about this as most articles about React Render just say "The Render function inserts HTML into the DOM".

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface Babylon_props { }

export const Babylon: FunctionComponent<Babylon_props> = (props) =>
{
    let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    let interval: number;
    //let x = 0;

    let tick = () => 
    {
        ctx.fillRect(x, x, 20, 20);
        setX(x + 10);
        //x += 10;
    }

    const [x, setX] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => 
    {
        console.log("Creating Babylon component...");

        canvas = document.getElementById("BblCanvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);

        interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);

        return () =>
        {
            console.log("Destroying Babylon component...");
            clearInterval(interval);
        };

    }, [x]);

    return (
        <canvas id="BblCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    )
}
```

Comment: `Is this virtual DOM at work?` Yes. Your DOM doesn't change so there is no need to create new elements.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks, I guess I have more reading to do on the virtual DOM.  Not that I'd do something like this, it doesn't seem particularly performant to go through the whole React render process to update a canvas.